# html: Onfocus, onblur, onkeypress is not working when used innerhtml while creating row for table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a row to my table with each cell having an input of type text. But

> Onfocus, onblur, onkeypress

are not working on the inputs of the newly created row. Following is my javascript code to add a row to the table:

```
function Addrow(){  
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(3);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML =
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell1' 
        + counter + '" id="cell1' + counter + '" value="0.0" '
        + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value=="0.0"?"":this.value;" 
        onblur="this.value = this.value==""?"0.0":this.value;"
        onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /></td>';
    cell2.innerHTML = 
        '<td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell2'
        + counter + '" id="cell2' + counter + '" value="0.0"'
        + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value=="0.0"?"":this.value;" 
        onblur="this.value = this.value==""?"0.0":this.value;" 
        onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /></td>';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell3' 
        + counter + '" id="cell3' + counter + '" value="0.0"'
        + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value=="0.0"?"":this.value;" 
        onblur="this.value = this.value==""?"0.0":this.value;" 
        onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /></td>';
    return false;
}
```

Javascript function to check if input is number or not

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) {
        alerts("Numbers or Decimal only!!!");
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your `cell*` variables are already `<td>` elements. You do not need to add `<td>...</td>` to their content

Comment: You have unescaped quotes characters. Eg `onfocus="this.value="` <- this one. Your console should be showing you an error. Something like _"Unexpected end of input"_

Comment: What does `isNumberKey` do?

Comment: @Phil my console is  not showing error but May I know what changes should I do for `onfocus="this.value="`

Comment: isNumberKey() is javascript function to check if input entered is number or not

Comment: What **exactly** does `isNumberKey()` do? Does it allow periods? How about commas?

Comment: @Phil thank you for pointing about `<td>...</td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**see code bellow:**(it is not a bug but in js `function` called with first lower-case letter)

```js
    function addRow(){  
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(3);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var counter=0;
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell1' + counter + '" id="cell1' + counter + '" value="0.0" '+
                        'onfocus="focusData(this)" onblur="blurData(this)" onkeypress=" isNumberKey(event)" />';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell2' + counter + '" id="cell2' + counter + '" value="0.0"' +
                              ' onfocus="focusData(this)" onblur="blurData(this)" onkeypress="isNumberKey(event)" />';
        cell3.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell3' + counter + '" id="cell3' + counter + '" value="0.0"' +
                              ' onfocus="focusData(this)" onblur="blurData(this)"  onkeypress="isNumberKey(event)" />';
       
    }
    function blurData(el) {
        el.value = el.value == '' ? "0.0" : el.value;
    }
    function focusData(el) {
        el.value = el.value == '0.0' ? '' : el.value;
    }
```

```html
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Row1 cell1</td>
        <td>Row1 cell2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row2 cell1</td>
        <td>Row2 cell2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row3 cell1</td>
        <td>Row3 cell2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="addRow()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying blur() and focus() is not working

Comment: Thank you very much. I did some changes to your code and now its works exactly the way I want. Thank you once again. Allow me to edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use addEventListener event delegation to dynamically created HTML

```js
var formControlList = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
for (var i = 0; i < formControlList.length; i++) 
{
    formControlList[i].addEventListener('blur', function(event) 
    {
       
    });
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say you **need** to

Comment: The event name is "blur", not "onblur" and it does **not** bubble up to the `document` so this won't work

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my code and text.

Comment: You're going to have to re-run this code every time a row is added

Comment: @MohammadAliRony Thank You for replying but not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `onblur` / `onfocus` / `onkeypress`, I'd just use `placeholder="0.0"` and `type="number"`

```js
function addRow() {
  const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  const row = table.insertRow()
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const cell = row.insertCell(i)
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = 'number' // only accept numeric input
    input.placeholder = '0.0' // placeholder disappears when a value is entered
    input.className = 'form-control'
    input.name = `cell${i+1}${row.rowIndex+1}`
    cell.appendChild(input)
  }
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="addRow()" type="button">Add a row</button></p>

<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but this doesn't work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you used the `quotes` within `quotes`. To represent a `"` character inside an HTML attribute delimited by `"` characters, use the entity `&quot;` .

I'd recommend attaching event listeners using JavaScript rather then using intrinsic event attributes though. It simplifies things greatly.

Note however, that browsers will not execute JavaScript added to the document with `innerHTML`. If you want to add a script programmatically, the use `createElement` or `appendChild` or ...

```js
function Addrow() {  
 var table = document.getElementById( 'myTable' ),
      row = table.insertRow(3),
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1),
    cell3 = row.insertCell(2),
      counter = 1;

 cell1.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell1' + counter + '" id="cell1' + counter + '" value="0.0" ' + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value==&quot;0.0&quot;?&quot;&quot;:this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==&quot;&quot;?&quot;0.0&quot;:this.value;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey( event )" /></td>';
 cell2.innerHTML = '<td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell2' + counter + '" id="cell2' + counter + '" value="0.0"' + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value==&quot;0.0&quot;?&quot;&quot;:this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==&quot;&quot;?&quot;0.0&quot;:this.value;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey( event )" /></td>';
 cell3.innerHTML = '<td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell3' + counter + '" id="cell3' + counter + '" value="0.0"' + ' onfocus="this.value = this.value==&quot;0.0&quot;?&quot;&quot;:this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==&quot;&quot;?&quot;0.0&quot;:this.value;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey( event )" /></td>';

 return false
}

function isNumberKey ( evt ) {
 var charCode = ( evt.which ) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

 if ( charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 ) ) {
  alert( 'Numbers or Decimal only!!!' );
  return false;
 }

 return true;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Addrow()" type="button">Add a row</button>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```